# Automatically pre-populate different Subject Line in mailto from text in different html pages with external js

Tags: javascript, html

I am managing a web site that has hundreds of html pages, and each page is devoted to a different article.

I would like to include an email link on each page, and I would like to use an external js script so that it is not necessary to change each individual page.

Perhaps there is something that may be placed on the pages around the name of the article ?

I am using the following code, and I would like to know how to modify it so that when the email link is clicked, the email message Subject line should automatically include the name of the article, which is different on each page, in this example: Igneous Rocks

Please let me know if this is possible, and what code to use, thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<script>
function SendLinkByMail(href) {
var subject= "";
var body = "I thought you might find this article interesting:\r\n\r\n<";
body += window.location.href;
body += ">";
var uri = "mailto:?subject=";
uri += encodeURIComponent(subject);
uri += "&body=";
uri += encodeURIComponent(body);
window.location.href = uri;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="javascript:(function()%7BSendLinkByMail()%3B%7D)()%3B">Email link to this page</a>
```

Igneous rocks etc, etc...

Comment: get the text from the title tag

Comment: It's not possible to get text from the title tag because the title tags are static, but the names of the articles change.

Comment: well you offered absolutely no indication of where that info might come from

Comment: My question above asks - Subject line should automatically include the name of the article, which is different on each page, in this example: Igneous Rocks

Comment: that doesn't explain where `igenous rocks` would come from. How would w know how you layout your content?

Comment: It isn't clear what you're asking us. It appears you already know how to "populate" the subject line using javascript. It is possible, you should use the code you have. There are no question marks in the post, so I don't know what else you need. Voted to close.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the site contains a HTML Tag which contains the title in a fixed structure (e.g. `<h1 id="artic">You are reading: Igneous rocks</h1>` and `<h1 id="artic">You are reading: Hello world</h1>` edit the line

`var subject= "";`

to

`var subject=document.getElementById('artic').innerHTML.substr(17);`

where the number is the position in the text of this element, where the name of the article begins.

Answer (score -1):

Just get the text for the title tag!
Use this to get it!document.title